# SQL Query, get random row from a filtered selection

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I use the following SQL query to get two random rows.

```
entry.sql
SELECT id, userID, img, points, votes 
FROM entry
WHERE rotation = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

Now I would like to filter the possible rows. I do this here by `rotation` but I want more.

I have a second and a third table which look like this:

```
users.sql    
ID | username

voted.sql
ID | userID | entryID | timestamp
```

I only want to get rows which the user hasn´t already voted on. So we should get all `entryIDs` for the `user` from `voted.sql` and make sure that the query above doesn´t pick them, how can I do this ?

Or would you save the data, in a different way, to make the `already voted check` easier ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a join or subquery to do this, like:

```
SELECT id, user.userID, entry.img, entry.points, entry.votes
FROM entry
WHERE userID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT userID 
                     FROM voted
                     WHERE userID = entry.userID);
```

Comment: Of course, you still need to add random ordering like you did before, or add additional conditions: I'm not quite sure what you exactly want to achieve.